# hiccup-like noise made while trying to speak when stabbed?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Say someone was stabbed and he bleeds but he remains conscious. Axiomatically if he were to speak he would speak with extreme difficulty.

What do you call the hiccup-like noise/sound he makes while he is attempting to talk or at pauses.

Comment: I would call it "gasping", or perhaps look up "gasping" in a thesaurus for further ideas.

Comment: @HotLicks: Please add *gasp* as an answer.

Comment: Depends where he was stabbed, of course. Stabbed in the buttock might be agonising but wouldn't necessarily cause a hiccupping noise when speaking. Stabbed in the throat would cause *gurgling*. But I agree with Drew that Hot Licks should claim the answer with *gasping* as the best option.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one would expect someone who was, say, stabbed in the chest to "gasp" as they attempted to breathe or speak.  "Gasping" would be characterized by spasmodic inhalation, accompanied by choking sounds.

Less pronounced gasping would occur if the victim were stabbed elsewhere, or were in severe pain for some other reason.  And at some point, as the pain moderates slightly, the gasping steadies a bit and becomes something more akin to "panting".

Answer (score 0):

In the context you describe a person would probably  ***[stutter](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/stutter%20)***:

> - [sputter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sputter), say inarticulately.
> - speak in a series of incoherent bursts as a result of indignation or some other strong emotion.

(ODO)

From [An Atlantean tale](https://books.google.it/books?id=05oDXGPOYqkC&pg=PA4&dq=he%20stuttered%20his%20last%20words&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7pIL1n9zMAhVKcRQKHeDcB1YQ6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=he%20stuttered%20his%20last%20words&f=false):

> - He coughed, then looked up and gasped for air. Even so, in his last words, he stuttered, “I...I wonder what remains for me out there...” His eyes closed as a peaceful smile came across his face. A great solemn silence fell upon...

Comment: So what's the answer? *Stutter* or *sputter*, or both?

Answer (score 0):

The hiccup is a spasm of the diaphragm used to pull air from, and push air to the lungs.
The resulting effect of trying to speak with a damaged chest or diaphragm might be termed, speaking ***spasmodically***.

Answer (score -1):

Try [stutter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stutter)

> to speak with involuntary disruption or blocking of speech .

Comment: Stutter is something entirely different.

Comment: @HotLicks Different from the op's question or different than what I defined?

Comment: A stutter is a neuromuscular disorder characterized by the rapid starting and stopping of sounds, particularly the initial sounds of words.  A person with a stutter ststststutters.

Comment: You may stutter also if you don't suffer from  neuromuscular disorders, because of fear for instance, or other strong emotions.

Comment: @Josh61 - The stutter is a relative of neuromuscular tremor.  In some people it will be present without provocation, while in others it's triggered by stress.  In any event, a stutter is a specific speech pattern, unlike what one would expect in the OP's scenario.